# Probability on multiple different percentages

Tags: probability, percentages

So, I'm trying to work on a tool that calculates the enhancement chances of an item and how many times it would mathematically take to reach a certain item level.

In the table below you can see the following:

- You have a $70\%$ chance to enhance a clean item to level $I.$
- You have a $40\%$ chance to enhance an item of level $I$ to level $II.$
- You have a $30\%$ chance to enhance an item of level $II$ to level $III.$
- You have a $20\%$ chance to enhance an item of level $III$ to level $IV.$
- You have a $10\%$ chance to enhance an item of level $IV$ to level $V$

```
|----------------------------------|
|  I  |  II  |  III |  IV  |   V   |
|----------------------------------|
| 70% | 40%  | 30%  | 20%  |  10%  |
|----------------------------------|
```

I'm trying to figure out a formula that helps me calculate what the success rate is when I attempt to enhance a clean item to item level $V$

**For example: if I try it $300 \times$, I'll be $65\%$ succesful.**

I know that I can use probability maths to calculate what my chances are of making a $40\%$ enhancement work after $5$ times $1-((1-0.4)^5)$, but I don't think that'll help me here.

Comment: It seems that you may just want to multiplying all of them together, as the enhancement looks like independent to each other. I assume you only have one chance only and fail if any one of the them fail.

Comment: So I do a probability on each item level (gives me $0,7$ $0,4$ $0,3$ $0,2$ and $0,1$), multiply the outcomes and I get $0,168%$ chance of pulling off a direct attempt to get from $I$ tot $V$. Do I need inverse probability to figure out how many attempts I need to get a certain success rate?

Comment: Figured it out, I isolated the exponent of my probability formula (since the exponent indicates how many attempts are required) I can then do something like this $\log_0,99832(x)$ where x is the desired success rate I seek. ($0.99832$ being $1-0.168%$)